# Create custom dialog box / PopUp / Alert in ionic 3

Tags: angular, sass, ionic3

I was looking for a way to apply css / sccs on popup / alert.
Wanted to design my Alert box, **bellow is the answer** which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

We can easily found-out the classes being apply on popup after inspecting as-
[image]
We have many classes as- dialog, alert-wrapper, alert-head, alert-title etc.
we can apply class as per our requirement.
Apply below code in related sccs file as-

```
/*for popup*/
ion-alert {

  &.alert-warning {
    .alert-head {
      background: map-get($colors, warning);
      color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 10px;  
    }
  }
  &.alert-danger {
    .alert-title {
      background: map-get($colors, #000);
      color: #000;
      font-size: 30px !important;
      font-family: times-new-roman;
      /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    }
    .alert-message {
      color: #000;
      font-size: 23px;
      font-family: monospace;;
    }
      .alert-wrapper {
        background-color: #skumar
        background-size: 200% 300%;
      }
      .button-inner {
        color: #000;
      }
  }
  &.alert-success {
    .alert-head {
      background: map-get($colors, success);
      color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/creating-custom-alerts-in-ionic/49723/10) which leads me to make my task accomplished